# Check if consecutive rows have identical value, if not insert new row between them

Tags: excel, vba

The task is to compare two consecutive rows, in the range from cell D1 to the last written cell in Column D.
If the value of a consecutive cell is equal to the value of the previous cell, i.e. D2=D1, go next, else insert a new row between the two values.

```vb
Sub Macro()

 'check rows
 
Dim a As Long
Dim b As Long, c As Long

a = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
For b = a To 2 Step -1
    c = b - 1

    If Cells(b, 4).Value = Cells(c, 4).Value Then
        If Cells(b, 4).Value <> Cells(c, 4).Value Then
            Rows("c").Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        End If
    End If
    
Next b
    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub InsertRows()
    Dim cl As Range
    With ActiveSheet
        Set cl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)
        Do Until cl.Row < 2
            Set cl = cl.Offset(-1)
            If cl.Value <> cl.Offset(1).Value Then cl.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
        Loop
    End With
End Sub
```

Side note. You can benefit from reading [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

[image] [image]